# TSQL Stored Procedure to import excel data

Tags: c#, excel, t-sql, linked-server, openrowset

I have created a query to import data from a large excel file into a SQL Server Table. When I execute it as a simple query, it runs perfectly, when I execute it as a stored procedure from SSMS it also runs fine. When I execute the SP from a C# application the SQL Server returns the following error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

interestingly, I accidentally left a debugging print statement in the SP, and SQL server also returns the SQL statement to my application. If i copy and paste that into SSMS, the query runs.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DataImporter]
   @SheetName varchar(20),
   @FilePath varchar(100),
   @TableName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
     

     
    IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
      SET @SQL = 'insert INTO [' + @TableName +'] SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                         ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @FilePath + ''',
                          ''SELECT * FROM [' + @SheetName + '] Where [Column] = ''''Value'''' AND [Column] =''''Value'''' AND  [Column] = ''''Value'''''')'
    ELSE
      SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO [' + @TableName +'] SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                         ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @FilePath + ''',
                          ''SELECT * FROM[' + @SheetName + '] Where [Column] = ''''Value'''' AND [Column] =''''Value'''' AND  [Column] = ''''Value'''''')'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
GO
```

as mentioned, if i just run this in a query window, it runs just fine:

```
insert INTO Table SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                         'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\folder\folder\folder\folder\name.xlsx',
                          'SELECT * FROM [Sheet$] Where [Column] = ''Value'' AND [Column] =''Value'' AND  [Column] = ''Value''')
```

C# Code

```
string _connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_conn"].ConnectionString;
            string query = report;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connection);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", fileName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SheetName", sheetname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", tableName);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: do a `print @SQL` to inspect the query before executing it

Comment: @Squirrel - I tried that and I can copy and paste it into an editor window and it runs fine.

Comment: then it should be fine also with`EXEC sp_executesql @SQL`

Comment: @Squirrel, I must have changed something along the way, I swear I did this and the copy/paste into new query window ran, but I did it again and then ran a compare in Notepad++ vs the known working once... noticed I had a missing letter when setting a table name. Thanks!